# Where to put an header file for a git repository if it is missing during make?

Tags: c++, git

I am installing from [source](https://github.com/libbitcoin/libbitcoin-system) and while `make` I get the error that a file is missing:

```
  CXX      src/math/libbitcoin_la-crypto.lo
  CXX      src/math/libbitcoin_la-elliptic_curve.lo
src/math/elliptic_curve.cpp:23:10: fatal error: secp256k1.h: No such file or directory
 #include <secp256k1.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

I think this header file can be found [here](https://github.com/libbitcoin/secp256k1/tree/master/include) so I could download it to include it. But I don't know where to put it.

Also, I am not sure if this is a usefull thing to do.

The [readme](https://github.com/libbitcoin/libbitcoin-system#autotools-advanced-users) says 'A minimal libbitcoin build requires boost and libsecp256k1.' so I installed `libsecp256k1` on my system already. But I am not certain that this is what they meant.

Comment: For Ubuntu, they likely meant to install `libsecp256k1-dev` rather than just `libsecp256k1` (which won't include header files)

Comment: Please see below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle, you can place header files anywhere you like - so long as you tell the compilier where they are using an appropriate `-I` directive:

```
g++ -Ipath/to/include/ ...
```

If the compiler is being run via a `make` it's often possible to pass such options via the appropriate `FLAGS` variable rather than trying to modify the Makefile. For C++ that would typically be `CXXFLAGS`, so you could do something like:

```
make "CXXFLAGS=-Ipath/to/include/"
```

If the Makefile already specifies a location for the software's private header files, you could simply place it there. Or you could place it in one of the default search locations - which you can find for gcc/g++ by executing

```
: | gcc -E -v -
```

and scrolling down to the `#include <...> search starts here` section. For user-installed headers, probably you should avoid all of those locations except `/usr/local/include`, since system packages may overwrite files in the others.

**However in your specific case, you should simply install the `libsecp256k1-dev` package, which will install the header file into `/usr/include` and will also install the libraries required to successfully link the application.**